# Express $f(n+2)=f(n+1)+f(n)+(n+1)$, where $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$, as a Fibonacci Function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations

I am currently solving a recursion problem.

If I have this function `f(n+2)=f(n+1)+f(n)+(n+1) where f(0)=0,f(1)=1`
It appears to me that this function can be reduced in form of fibonacci function.Can anyone tell me how this can be expressed as Fibonacci function.

The answer is `f(n)=2(fib(n+2)-1)-n`.

Can anyone explain how?

Comment: since you start from $n=0$ can I propose you shift your index by $2$ as follows $$f(n+2) = f(n+1) + f(n) + n + 1$$ much easier to interpret. Maybe this can help you.

Comment: When you say 'it appears to me', what have you actually tried so far?

Comment: I know fib(n)=fib(n-1)+fib(n-2) where f(0)=0 and f(1)=1.Since for this problem also f(0)=0 and f(1)=1,I thought it might be related to Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: I get $f(n)=-2-n+F_{n+3}$

Comment: `f(n) = 2(fib(n+2) - 1) - n` is the answer, can you tell me how? where fib(n) is nth Fibonacci number.

Comment: @AdityaMishra Stop asking for the answer to be spoonfed to you -- you've done that below both answers. Try to work from there (either of the two answers). If you are stuck doing so, **then** ask for help (something may be wrong, or non-obvious, maybe)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: Note that the original question, which is the question in the title, has $f(2)=1$, whereas the edited question has $f(2)=2$. Which is the correct question?

Comment: In the answer you cite $f(1)=2(F_3-1)-1=1$, but $f(1)=0$ according to the question. The title, question, and proposed answer do not match. Will the real question please stand up?

Comment: Sorry,Sir I typed the question incorrectly that day,later when I saw it I thought someone else has edited it.So sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Original Question**

The equation that needs to be satisfied is
$$
\left(S^2-S-1\right)f(n)=n+1
$$
where $Sf(n)=f(n+1)$ is the shift operator.
$$
\begin{align}
\left(S^2-S-1\right)(\color{#C00}{-2}\color{#090}{-n}\color{#00F}{+F_{n+3}})
&=\color{#C00}{2}\color{#090}{+n-1}\color{#00F}{+0}\\
&=n+1
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, $f(0)=-2+F_3=0$ and $f(1)=-3+F_4=0$.

Therefore, the solution to the original question, and the question in the title, is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f(n)=F_{n+3}-n-2}
$$

---

**The Edited Question**

The equation that needs to be satisfied is
$$
\left(S^2-S-1\right)f(n)=n+2
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\left(S^2-S-1\right)(\color{#C00}{-3}\color{#090}{-n}\color{#00F}{+2F_{n+1}+F_{n+2}})
&=\color{#C00}{3}\color{#090}{+n-1}\color{#00F}{+0}\\
&=n+2
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, $f(0)=-3+2F_1+F_2=0$ and $f(1)=-4+2F_2+F_3=0$.

Therefore, the solution to the edited question is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f(n)=2F_{n+1}+F_{n+2}-n-3}
$$

---

**The Finally Edited Question**

The equation that needs to be satisfied is
$$
\left(S^2-S-1\right)f(n)=n+1
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\left(S^2-S-1\right)(\color{#C00}{-2}\color{#090}{-n}\color{#00F}{+2F_{n+2}})
&=\color{#C00}{2}\color{#090}{+n-1}\color{#00F}{+0}\\
&=n+1
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, $f(0)=-2+2F_2=0$ and $f(1)=-3+2F_3=1$.

Therefore, the solution to the finally edited question is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f(n)=2F_{n+2}-n-2}
$$

Comment: The edit was not made by me. Your first solution is wrong as according to your solution  `f(1)=3-1-2=0` but in original question `f(1)=1`.

Comment: All the substantive edits *were* made by you. The edit by David G. Stork did not change your question at all. The question, up until your last edit, had $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Changing the question after so many answers is not good, especially if you call one of those answers **wrong** because of that change. The **original** question had $f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Add $a(n+2)+b$ on both sides, for some $a,b$ to be specified. You get, for all $n$,
$$
f(n+2)+a(n+2)+b = f(n+1)+f(n)+n+2+a(n+2)+b
$$
which, once simplified, gives
$$
f(n+2)+a(n+2)+b = f(n+1)+f(n)+(a+1)n+2a+2+b\tag{1}
$$
We want the RHS to look like 
$$
\left(f(n+1)+a(n+1)+b\right)+\left(f(n)+an+b\right)
$$
i.e. to 
$$f(n+1)+f(n)+2an+a+2b\tag{2}$$

For (1) and (2) to be equal, we need $a+1=2a$ and $2a+2+b=a+2b$, i.e. $a=1$ and $b=3$. With this choice, we get, setting $$g(n)\stackrel{\rm def}{=} f(n)+n+3\tag{3},$$ that
$$
g(n+2) = g(n+1)+g(n)
$$
which is a Fibonacci sequence. Once you have $g$, you get $f$ by (3).

Comment: When I saw the answer it says `f(n) = 2(fib(n+2) - 1) - n` . Can you tell me how it came.

Comment: @AdityaMishra Solve it, and check. I.e., find what $g$ is, and then look what it gives for $f$.

Comment: Note that $g(0)=f(0)+3=3$, $g(1)=f(1)+1+3=4$. Use that to find $g(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f_n=g_n+an+b$ where $g_n=g_{n-1}+g_{n-2}$ therefore:$$f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}+{n-1}\to g_n+an+b=g_{n-1}+an-a+b+g_{n-2}+an-2a+b+{n-1}$$so we get from here:$$a=-1,b=-2$$which leads us to$$f_n=g_n-n-2$$also $$g_n=Ar_1^n+Br_2^n$$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are roots of $r^2=r+1$ so we get from here:$$g_n=A\phi^n+B(1-\phi)^n$$where $\phi$ is Golden Ratio. Also $g_0=2$ and $g_1=3$ therefore:$$g_n=(1+\frac{{2}}{\sqrt 5})\phi^n+(1-\frac{{2}}{\sqrt 5})(1-\phi)^n$$and finally$$f_n=(1+\frac{{2}}{\sqrt 5})\phi^n+(1-\frac{{2}}{\sqrt 5})(1-\phi)^n-n-2$$

Comment: When I saw the answer it says `f(n) = 2(fib(n+2) - 1) - n` . Can you tell me how it came.